# Welcome mail is not send during checkout

Tags: checkout, email, ce-1.7.0.2

If I register a new user during checkout only the order mail is send to the user. Not the welcome mail. If I register a new user on

> /customer/account/create/

the welcome mail is send.

Is this normal? Is there a setting to change this?

**Update**

I found this function `_involveNewCustomer()` in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php:745
```

Looks to me like this mail should have been send during checkout. Still wonder why it did not?

Answer (score 1):

From https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-9767

> KNOWN ISSUES:
>
> Magento received reports that customer registration after checkout
>   might fail if option to 'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout' is
>   enabled. This results in customers not being registered, but checking
>   out as guests. Magento is working on updated version of the patch. As
>   a workaround, disabling the 'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout'
>   option will revert the incorrect behavior.

Because of this the user is ordering as guest even if he selects register and no welcome mail is send because no account was created.

Solution is to get SUPEE-9767 V2. Revert V1 and install V2:

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2017-05-25-09-31-32.sh --revert
./PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.7.0.2_v2-2017-07-11-11-01-10.sh
```